# Not able to convert Azure ad public key string to PublicRSAKey

Tags: scala, azure, rsa, public-key-encryption

Background:
I am trying to validate azure ad jwt access token which is in RSA256. I'll be using jjwt or jwt-scala to validate the token. In order to use them, I need to convert the azure public key which is string to RSAPublicKey instance.

Public key:

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQZSAeaqWig4BHC1ksmNNcgjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAtMSswKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3MubmV0MB4XDTE3MDUwNjAwMDAwMFoXDTE5MDUwNzAwMDAwMFowLTErMCkGA1UEAxMiYWNjb3VudHMuYWNjZXNzY29udHJvbC53aW5kb3dzLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJL7dVZkeJ8JDTPIzFNMJo9oEkvDc52zrdqWSOmex0E/3rBe1tfRmUe2O9l6NYuc10QzPaNxnkyIwa5698suNUPxGlEOwvm/h5oPeFcuxAWcgYYv5s589HWFrNjCF8EfOjZ4vU5oE1744EzxdmBiaGbeE8HDBXn1vK4owlcjawgQNF7KQ6LjSWr7xtARDF2IoKE4RYy0V0uVN4eAQ3zWRWWUt3cpYjTl34EZ9pO6CE8/If7noj75g0RYd/AHkIMdXBC4SlnNz+boLbba2ksIB+5z9jVILjvZwqx7i+k2filqZkVmasB/o2ChUFbdwg6c8DTOlyS/qB25dcfoCN2GF+cCAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFGKpXQNrF5IoxS6bL4F92+gxOJlIMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQA3HgW5SoHlvvQVxqqi+mtscDZLhNfe13iG/nx8Er5il82b79RVydNs+f9sYxc4T4ctnrZu7x5e7jInJedNdAlrPorBdw+SfvKJsmiNndXugMew1FlcQTQVIFDCbziaJav8rKyMxPfeKkc1aixbajWZkKg6OPmmJn2ceTocbn8PMQy20xNvcWUwgF5FZZIuPqu6feOLJcUIYw+0JFZ265xka30QXpmytcIxajIzpD4PRdCIBuVSqgXacAs4t4+w+OhnosD72yvXck8M4GwX1j+vcuyw0yhDGNMmqsHWP7H3jnJiGDrKhhdVyplzDhTfv2Whbv/dIDn+meLE3yyC5yGL-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

Have also tried removing BEGIN and END certificate.

What I have tried (there are a lot of examples like the one below)

```
byte[] publicBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(azurePubKey);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
  at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:205)
  at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
  ... 43 elided
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
  at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:398)
  at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:403)
  at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:84)
  at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:298)
  at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:201)
  ... 44 more
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an X509EncodedKeySpec, you have an X509 certificate. I don't know scala but here an example in Java showing how to get a Public key out of this:

```
  public static PublicKey parsePublicKey() throws CertificateException {
        String cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        cert = cert.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "");
        cert = cert.replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "");
        byte[] der = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cert);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(der));
        return certificate.getPublicKey();
    }
}
```